# Is there a velocity port in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, velocity, vtl

I know apache velocity is available for Java and .NET.
Is there also a port to JavaScript?
My aim is to translate VTL templates inside the browser without a roundtrip to the web server.

Comment: What's the point? There are already hundreds of templating languages for JS as well as NodeJS.

Comment: @elclanrs: Maybe he wants to reuse existing VTL documents.

Comment: Right, I guess that's the only reason to want this as far as I can tell. I haven't seen VTL for JS but I could be wrong...

Comment: The reason is...I don't want to learn another templating language^^
Just kidding...
No I have used velocity since years now and I think there is nothing better.

Comment: My next question should be. Is there a good templating engine like velocity which is also supported by [code mirror](http://codemirror.net) and has got a JavaScript implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [jsVelocity](https://github.com/vapour/jsVelocity). It doesn't look like it supports all Velocity features, but it's a start.